# What distribution do you get from this broken random shuffle?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, math, random, shuffle

The famous Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm can be used to randomly permute an array A of length N:

```
For k = 1 to N
    Pick a random integer j from k to N
    Swap A[k] and A[j]
```

A common mistake that I've been told over and over again not to make is this:

```
For k = 1 to N
    Pick a random integer j from 1 to N
    Swap A[k] and A[j]
```

That is, instead of picking a random integer from k to N, you pick a random integer from 1 to N.

What happens if you make this mistake?  I know that the resulting permutation isn't uniformly distributed, but I don't know what guarantees there are on what the resulting distribution will be.  In particular, does anyone have an expression for the probability distributions over the final positions of the elements?

Comment: Do you really want 1-based indices?

Comment: This sounds familiar.  Was this discussed on SO within the past two months or was it on programmers.SE?

Comment: @oosterwal- I asked this question about three weeks ago and didn't get a good answer, so I put a Large Bounty on it to help spur some interest in it.  Hopefully someone will be able to enlighten all of us!

Comment: I don't have an answer (yet), but one thing I've noticed is that each card is most likely to be found in the position just behind where it started.  Also, both the *first card* and the *last position* are evenly distributed - that is, the first card has equal probability to end up in any position, and every card has equal probability to end up in the last position.  Any correct solution must have these characteristics.

Comment: @Svante: why not? Lot of languages, starting with Pascal which was often used to describe algorithms, and including Lua, has indices starting at 1. IIRC, Pascal allows to start array indices at any number, but defaults to 1.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**An Empirical Approach.**

Let's implement the erroneous algorithm in Mathematica:

```
p = 10; (* Range *)
s = {}
For[l = 1, l <= 30000, l++, (*Iterations*)
   a = Range[p];
   For[k = 1, k <= p, k++, 
     i = RandomInteger[{1, p}];
     temp = a[[k]];
     a[[k]] = a[[i]];
     a[[i]] = temp
   ];
   AppendTo[s, a];
]
```

Now get the number of times each integer is in each position:

```
r = SortBy[#, #[[1]] &] & /@ Tally /@ Transpose[s]
```

Let's take three positions in the resulting arrays and plot the frequency distribution for each integer in that position:

For position 1 the freq distribution is:

[image]

For position 5 (middle)

[image]

And for position 10 (last):

[image]

and here you have the distribution for all positions plotted together:

[image]

Here you have a better statistics over 8 positions:

[image]

**Some observations:**

- For all positions the probability of
  "1" is the same (1/n).
- The probability matrix is symmetrical
  with respect to the big anti-diagonal
- So, the probability for any number in the last
  position is also uniform (1/n)

You may visualize those properties looking at the starting of all lines from the same point (first property) and the last horizontal line (third property).

The second property can be seen from the following matrix representation example, where the rows are the positions, the columns are the occupant number, and the color represents the experimental probability:

[image]

For a 100x100 matrix:

[image]

**Edit**

Just for fun, I calculated the exact formula for the second diagonal element (the first is 1/n). The rest can be done, but it's a lot of work.

```
h[n_] := (n-1)/n^2 + (n-1)^(n-2) n^(-n)
```

Values verified from n=3 to 6 ( {8/27, 57/256, 564/3125, 7105/46656} )

**Edit**

Working out a little the general explicit calculation in @wnoise answer, we can get a little more info.

Replacing 1/n by p[n], so the calculations are hold unevaluated, we get for example for the first part of the matrix with n=7 (click to see a bigger image):

[image]

Which, after comparing with results for other values of n, let us identify some known integer sequences in the matrix:

```
{{  1/n,    1/n      , ...},
 {... .., A007318, ....},
 {... .., ... ..., ..},
 ... ....,
 {A129687, ... ... ... ... ... ... ..},
 {A131084, A028326 ... ... ... ... ..},
 {A028326, A131084 , A129687 ... ....}}
```

You may find those sequences (in some cases with different signs) in the wonderful http://oeis.org/

Solving the general problem is more difficult, but I hope this is a start

Answer (score 32):

The "common mistake" you mention is shuffling by random transpositions. This problem was studied in full detail by Diaconis and Shahshahani in [Generating a random permutation with random transpositions (1981)](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00535487). They do a complete analysis of stopping times and convergence to uniformity. If you cannot get a link to the paper, then please send me an e-mail and I can forward you a copy. It's actually a fun read (as are most of Persi Diaconis's papers).

If the array has repeated entries, then the problem is slightly different. As a shameless plug, this more general problem is addressed by myself, Diaconis and Soundararajan in Appendix B of [A Rule of Thumb for Riffle Shuffling (2011)](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/%7Ecgates/PERSI/papers/redblack.pdf).

Comment: Persi Diaconis is awesome... though when he lectures he never looks at the people he's talking to. :-)

Comment: Does the 1981 paper actually address this particular situation? I thought the problem as state was looking at the distribution of permutations of the form (1 a_1)(2 a_2)...(n a_n) where each a_i is chosen uniformly from 1..n.

Comment: Could you summarize the result for those of us who can't access the paper?

Comment: @mhum: I believe you are correct that it doesn't quite. While I don't have immediate access to the 1981 paper, the corresponding results in "Group Representations in Probability and Statistics" cover uniformly random transpositions, not these ones where the transpositions involve fixed elements.  (They generalize nicely to uniformly random over any conjugacy class, but I can't see how to get them to directly apply here.)

Comment: It's unfortunate that this got the automatic bounty, as it doesn't really answer the question...

Comment: I don't know how it did considering belisarius had a (deservedly) higher rated answer.

Comment: @Peng Because I posted my answer before the bounty was started

Comment: This doesn't answer the given question.

Answer (score 15):

Let's say

- `a = 1/N`
- `b = 1-a`
- B<sub>i</sub>(k) is the probability matrix after `i` swaps for the `k`th element. i.e the answer to the question "where is `k` after `i` swaps?". For example B<sub>0</sub>(3) = `(0 0 1 0 ... 0)` and B<sub>1</sub>(3) = `(a 0 b 0 ... 0)`. What you want is B<sub>N</sub>(k) for every k.
- K<sub>i</sub> is an NxN matrix with 1s in the i-th column and i-th row, zeroes everywhere else, e.g:

[image: kappa_2]

- I<sub>i</sub> is the identity matrix but with the element x=y=i zeroed. E.g for i=2:

[image: I_2]

- A<sub>i</sub> is

[image: Ai= bIi + aKi]

Then,

[image: B_n]

But because B<sub>N</sub>(k=1..N) forms the identity matrix, the probability that any given element i will at the end be at position j is given by the matrix element (i,j) of the matrix:

[image: solution matrix]

For example, for N=4:

[image: B_4]

As a diagram for N = 500 (color levels are 100*probability):

[image: B_500]

The pattern is the same for all N>2:

- The **most probable ending position** for k-th element **is k-1**.
- The **least probable** ending position **is k** for **k < N*ln(2)**, position **1** otherwise

Comment: It's easy to calculate analytic results even for large Ns, but the expressions are too "messy" to include here.

Comment: This appears to be correct, but.. how did you come up with this?  Is this the same as [wnoise's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131341/5132404#5132404)? (sorry, I'm afraid I don't understand stochastic matrices..)

Comment: @EElvex I would to know how you calculated this.

Answer (score 13):

I knew I had seen this question before...

" [why does this simple shuffle algorithm produce biased results? what is a simple reason?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859253/why-does-this-simple-shuffle-algorithm-produce-biased-results-what-is-a-simple-r) " has a lot of good stuff in the answers, especially a link to a [blog by Jeff Atwood on Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html).

As you may have already guessed, based on the answer by @belisarius, the exact distribution is highly dependent on the number of elements to be shuffled.  Here's Atwood's plot for a 6-element deck:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link/picture, but all that this confirms is that you get something non-uniform.  I was hoping more for an analytic solution to what the actual distribution is, though.

Comment: Upvoted for sharing the Jeff Atwood link, which also describes a way of deriving the distribution - the broken shuffle has n^n equally likely choices of random numbers, mapping to n! outputs. I don't think you're going to get an analytical solution; just a numerical one for small values of n.

Answer (score 9):

What a lovely question!  I wish I had a full answer.

Fisher-Yates is nice to analyze because once it decides on the first element, it leaves it alone.  The biased one can repeatedly swap an element in and out of any place.

We can analyze this the same way we would a Markov chain, by describing the actions as stochastic transition matrices acting linearly on probability distributions.  Most elements get left alone, the diagonal is usually (n-1)/n.  On pass k, when they don't get left alone, they get swapped with element k, (or a random element if they are element k).  This is 1/(n-1) in either row or column k.  The element in both row and column k is also 1/(n-1).  It's easy enough to multiply these matrices together for k going from 1 to n.

We do know that the element in last place will be equally likely to have originally been anywhere because the last pass swaps the last place equally likely with any other.  Similarly, the first element will be equally likely to be placed anywhere.  This symmetry is because the transpose reverses the order of matrix multiplication.  In fact, the matrix is symmetric in the sense that row i is the same as column (n+1 - i).  Beyond that, the numbers don't show much apparent pattern. These exact solutions do show agreement with the simulations run by belisarius: In slot i, The probability of getting j decreases as j raises to i, reaching its lowest value at i-1, and then jumping up to its highest value at i, and decreasing until j reaches n.

In Mathematica I generated each step with

```
 step[k_, n_] := Normal[SparseArray[{{k, i_} -> 1/n, 
                      {j_, k} -> 1/n, {i_, i_} -> (n - 1)/n} , {n, n}]]
```

(I haven't found it documented anywhere, but the first matching rule is used.)
The final transition matrix can be calculated with:

```
Fold[Dot, IdentityMatrix[n], Table[step[m, n], {m, s}]]
```

`ListDensityPlot` is a useful visualization tool.

**Edit (by belisarius)**

Just a confirmation. The following code gives the same matrix as in @Eelvex's answer:

```
step[k_, n_] := Normal[SparseArray[{{k, i_} -> (1/n), 
                      {j_, k} -> (1/n), {i_, i_} -> ((n - 1)/n)}, {n, n}]];
r[n_, s_] := Fold[Dot, IdentityMatrix[n], Table[step[m, n], {m, s}]];
Last@Table[r[4, i], {i, 1, 4}] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Sounds interesting but I didn't get what your probability distributions are *on* -- seems to me that each state in the Markov chain you're describing needs to the specify the order of the entire n elements (i.e. an n-element problem requires an (n!)-state Markov chain).  Is that what you mean?  Also not sure about your reasoning that the last element is equally likely to have come from anywhere -- that is true iff all n elements are uniformly randomly distributed after the 1st n-1 elements have been processed, and I don't believe that's the case (or at least I'd like to see a proof).

Comment: The states are the n slots.  Entry i,j in a transition matrix is the chance of going from slot i to slot j.  Turning a transition matrix into a distribution on "where element i ended up" is just picking out row i.  The distribution for "where element j came from" is just picking out column j.  This indeed doesn't give counts for the  permutations, just for where elements end up.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: The last operation swaps the last element with any element with equal probability.  No matter the distribution prior to this, the last element is chosen at random from all of them.

Comment: Thanks, after doing some algebra I understand your last point now.  Regarding the Markov states: so you mean you are tracking the movement (= probabilities of being in each slot) of a *particular* element?  (E.g. suppose initially the ith element was i.  Then we could say that the column vector transpose([0, 0, 1, 0, ..., 0]) represents the initial probability distribution of the location of element 3, and that premultiplying this by the transition matrix corresponding to the 1st swap would give the probability distribution of the location of element 3 after this step...

Comment: @j_random_hacker: that's exactly right.  The transition matrix tracks all of these probabilities simultaneously for all elements, but does not track correlations (which could be done by tracking the permutations directly).

Comment: Ah good.  I was halfway through writing another comment but I think I'm on the right page now.  Basically the shuffle is uniformly random iff, for any element i, the result of multiplying together the n transition matrices followed by a column vector with 1 in row i and 0 elsewhere equals [1/n, 1/n, ..., 1/n].  That's equivalent to requiring that each column in the product of transition matrices equals that, which is equivalent to requiring that every single entry in the product matrix is 1/n.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia's page on the Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle#Implementation_errors) has a description and example of exactly what will happen in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but part of the reason I asked this question is that the Wikipedia article just states that you aren't going to get a uniform distribution, not what that non-uniform distribution looks like mathematically.  That is, there's no discussion of the probability of a particular element ending up in a particular place.

Comment: @templatetypedef: There is a figure for that for a simple case (I believe 6 or 7 elements).  I know it is not a fully general answer, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can compute the distribution using [stochastic matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix). Let the matrix A(i,j) describe the probability of the card originally at position i ending up in position j. Then the kth swap has a matrix Ak given by `Ak(i,j) = 1/N` if `i == k` or `j == k`, (the card in position k can end up anywhere and any card can end up at position k with equal probability), `Ak(i,i) = (N - 1)/N` for all `i != k` (every other card will stay in the same place with probability (N-1)/N) and all other elements zero.

The result of the complete shuffle is then given by the product of the matrices `AN ... A1`.

I expect you're looking for an algebraic description of the probabilities; you can get one by expanding out the above matrix product, but it I imagine it will be fairly complex!

UPDATE: I just spotted wnoise's equivalent answer above! oops...

Answer (score 3):

I've looked into this further, and it turns out that this distribution has been studied at length. The reason it's of interest is because this "broken" algorithm is (or was) used in the RSA chip system.

In [Shuffling by semi-random transpositions](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.PR/0404438), Elchanan Mossel, Yuval Peres, and Alistair Sinclair study this and a more general class of shuffles. The upshot of that paper appears to be that it takes `log(n)` broken shuffles to achieve near random distribution.

In *The bias of three pseudorandom shuffles* (*Aequationes Mathematicae*,  22, 1981, 268-292), Ethan Bolker and David Robbins analyze this shuffle and determine that the total variation distance to uniformity after a single pass is 1, indicating that it is not very random at all. They give asympotic analyses as well.

Finally, Laurent Saloff-Coste and Jessica Zuniga found a nice upper bound in their study of inhomogeneous Markov chains.

Answer (score 2):

This question is begging for an [interactive visual matrix diagram](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/compare.html) analysis of the broken shuffle mentioned. Such a tool is on the page [Will It Shuffle? - Why random comparators are bad](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/compare.html) by Mike Bostock.

Bostock has put together an excellent tool that analyzes random comparators. In the dropdown on that page, choose **naïve swap (random ↦ random)** to see the broken algorithm and the pattern it produces.

His page is informative as it allows one to see the immediate effects a change in logic has on the shuffled data. For example:

This matrix diagram using a non-uniform and very-biased shuffle is produced using a naïve swap (we pick from "1 to N") with code like this:

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var n = array.length, i = -1, j;
    while (++i < n) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
        t = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i];
        array[i] = t;
    }
}
```

[image: biased shuffle]

But if we implement a non-biased shuffle, where we pick from "k to N" we should see a diagram like this:

[image]

where the distribution is uniform, and is produced from code such as:

```
function FisherYatesDurstenfeldKnuthshuffle( array ) {
    var pickIndex, arrayPosition = array.length;
    while( --arrayPosition ) {
        pickIndex = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( arrayPosition + 1 ) );
        array[ pickIndex ] = [ array[ arrayPosition ], array[ arrayPosition ] = array[ pickIndex ] ][ 0 ];
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you would include more information here and not hide it behind a link.

Comment: I disagree. I saw no need to attempt to repeat the excellent replies already given by **daoudc**, **wnoise**, **Eelvex**, and especially **belisarius is forth**. All that was missing from the replies on this page was some kind of interactive model. The link provides it.

Answer (score 1):

The excellent answers given so far are concentrating on the distribution, but you have asked also **"What happens if you make this mistake?"** - which is what I haven't seen answered yet, so I'll give an explanation on this:

The Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm picks 1 out of n elements, then 1 out of n-1 remaining elements and so forth.

You can implement it with two arrays a1 and a2 where you remove one element from a1 and insert it into a2, but the algorithm does it in place (which means, that it needs only one array), as is explained [here](http://datagenetics.com/blog/november42014/index.html) (Google: "Shuffling Algorithms Fisher-Yates DataGenetics") very well.

If you don't remove the elements, they can be randomly chosen again which produces the biased randomness. This is exactly what the 2nd example your are describing does. The first example, the Knuth-Fisher-Yates algorithm, uses a cursor variable running from k to N, which remembers which elements have already been taken, hence avoiding to pick elements more than once.

Comment: Do you think, you could replace the "here" by something more googleable?

Comment: Done, I have added a google search hint - however, "here" was a link already.

Comment: That's the problem with *here* links: the intent may be obvious to the writer, but not to the reader (before following it). It's like pointing into a landscape saying *look there!* The more problematic thing is that sometimes web pages vanish, or entire sites are shut down (hopefully archived before): that's the time when a simple *here* becomes pointless. Nevertheless thanks for taking my suggestion into account.

Comment: @Wolf: Good point, I didn't think about that before. You are right, if the content moves, the google search might still be helpful. Thank you for bringing this to my attention!