# Why does the following code NOT generate permutations randomly?

Tags: algorithm, permutation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What distribution do you get from this broken random shuffle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131341/what-distribution-do-you-get-from-this-broken-random-shuffle)

This is from Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual.

Assume that myrand(a, b) generates a random number between a and b inclusive.

The following code generates permutations uniformly at random

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    swap( a[i], a[myrand(i, n-1)]);
```

whereas the following doesn't.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    swap( a[i], a[myrand(0, n-1)]);
```

The question is, why?

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to generate permutations? It looks like it's shuffling the array (it looks like the Fisher-Yates shuffle).

Comment: A shuffled array is a permutation of that array.

Comment: @Mat: Well, yes, but only a single permutation. "Generate permutations" is more general (and harder).

Comment: @delnan: if you call it more than once it generates permutations at random. I don't think it's unusual to say for example that the function `socket` "creates sockets", although of course each call to it only creates one socket. You wouldn't *document* it "creates sockets", but informally that's what the function does (as opposed to what a single call to the function does).

Answer (score 2):

In the first case there are exactly n! possible paths for execution of the function (first rand has n possibilities, the second has n-1 ...). Since each of the n! possible permutations correspojnds to exactly one of these, they are uniformly distributed.

In the second case, there are n^n possible paths of distribution (n possible chioces the first time, n the second...). This does *not* map uniformly to the permutations so the distribution is uneven.

To check it out "by hand", generate all possibilities for a small n, like 3

```
numbers chosen  generated permutation
(0,0,0)         (2,0,1)
...              ...
```

Comment: True mathematically, but not even the first algorithm can actually produce all permutations in practice. Note that pseudo-random number generators maintain a finite state (eg, a seed), and thus RNGs are necessarily doomed to start repeating "random" numbers after 2^b calls where b is the number of bits of state maintained by the RNG. Since b is fixed, and n! grows super-exponentially, there are more possible permutations of sequences of length n for even moderately sized n than there are RNG states for even the largest b used in practice, so RNGs cannot possibly produce every permumation.