# Generate an uniform random permutation

Tags: algorithm

I am not sure whether the following pseudo-code can generate an `uniformly random permutation`:

```
PERMUTATE(A): 
    n = A.length
    for i = 1 to n
        swap A[i] and A[random(1,n)]
```

It seems to be right, but can anyone give me a rigorous proof to verify its correctness or wrongness ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This solution is biased, you want the [Fisher Yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) [which is similar] for non biased permutation. [basically, you need to swap with `random(i,n)` instead of with `random(1,n)`]

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5131341/572670) discusses how and why your solution is biased.