# Are there any algorithms for scrambling a word?

Tags: c, algorithm, cpu-word, scramble

I am trying to make a word scrambler and am wondering if there are any algorithms I should use or if I should just build it from scratch. Any pointers would be helpful!

Comment: How is that different from shuffling an array?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "scrambling a word"?

Comment: Should the scrambled word be meaningful or purely random?

Comment: purely random, and sorry, it is the same as shuffling an array I was just looking for good algorithms and had trouble finding them through a google search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard algorithm for finding a random permutation of a sequence of elements (or, in your case, letters in a word) is the **[Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)**, which in linear time produces a truly random permutation of a sequence of elements.  The algorithm is well-established and many standard libraries provide implementations of it (for example, the C++ `std::random_shuffle` algorithm is typically implemented using this algorithm), so you may be able to find a prewritten implementation.  If not, the algorithm is extremely easy to implement, and here's some pseudocode for it:

```
for each index i = 0 to n - 1, inclusive:
    choose a random index j in the range i to n - 1, inclusive.
    swap A[i] and A[j]
```

Be careful when implementing this that when picking a random index, you do **not** pick an index between 0 and n-1 inclusive; this produces a nonuniform distribution of letters (you can read more about that [in this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131341/what-distribution-do-you-get-from-this-broken-random-shuffle)).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Go with the [Knuth Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (AKA the Fisher–Yates Shuffle).  It has the desirable feature of ensuring that every permutation of the set is equally likely.  [Here's a link](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#C) to an implementation in C (along with implementations in other languages) that works on arbitrarily sized objects.