# Scramble a String Using C

Tags: c, string, scramble

I've just started learning C this semester after primarily learning Java and I've been asked to create a program which allows the user to enter in a string, and then scramble the letters inside their string.

```
#include <stdio.h> //Alows input/output operations
#include <stdlib.h> //Standard utility operations

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) //Main method
{
  printf("------------------------\n");
  printf("WELCOME TO THE SCRAMBLER\n");
  printf("------------------------\n\n");

  char userString[50]; //Declaring the user string 
  printf("Please input a String :> "); //Iforms the user to enter a string
  scanf("%s", userString); //Allows the user to enter in a string

  char targetLetter[2]; //Declaring the target letter
  char replaceLetter[2]; //Declaring the replace letter

  while(1)
  {


  }
}
```

This is what I currently have, I just need help/advice on how to actually scramble the string. The user should be able to scramble the string as many times as they like, until they enter a specific character, then the program terminates. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: If by scrambling you mean just shuffling the letters into a random order, you could use a [fisher-yates shuffle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343797/is-this-c-implementation-of-fisher-yates-shuffle-correct).

Comment: @indiv Thanks for the reply. What I'm aiming for is so the user can select a letter from their created string and replace it with another letter/character.

Comment: [This](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/8631023/are-there-any-algorithms-for-scrambling-a-word) will interest you.

Answer (score -2):

The first thing you want to do is think to a simple algorithm to shuffle the string.

(Note that `scanf()` & `%s` will read a string until a space is found after hitting enter. Therefore, 'hello world' would be just 'hello'. Instead use `gets()`  if you need to acquire even space characters).

A simple shuffle function could be:

```
void mix (char * string) {
    //Get string length
    int len = strlen(string);
    int i;

    char tmp;

    for (i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        //Loop every char till the middle of the string
        //Save the current char
        tmp = string[i];
        //Put in this position the opposite char in the string
        string[i] = string[len - i];
        //Replace the opposite char
        string[len - i] = tmp;
    }
}

//If you input hello you should get olleh
```

However this is not what you was exactly looking for, but I would suggest you to make two or three functions like this and in the `while()` loop keep calling them one by one.

Before the loop restarts just ask the user for a `char` with a scanf().

The while loop should be something like:

```
while (char != 'a') {
  //Mix the string
  mix_1();
  mix_2();
  mix_3();
  //Ask char again
  scanf("%c",&char);
  //Loop goes on till char != a
}
```

Hope this helped.In this case a simple vote on this answer would really be helpful for me.

Cheers

Comment: No, use `fgets()` instead!

Comment: Even if it throws a warning, for his purposes he should definitely be fine.
Thanks for the tip anyway

Comment: Problem is he uses a deprecated function rather than a safe function he gets to be able to use into the future.

Comment: [Why the `gets()` function is dangerous and should never be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Comment: Again, I'm not saying it is safe, but for this purposes will just be fine. I have been developing C programs for the past 6 months and have always used gets. That is why I suggested it. This said, I'm aware of the problems related to it

Comment: @FoxNos: `gets()` is declared in `<stdio.h>`, not `<string.h>`. Unless your compiler conforms to the 2011 ISO C standard; then `gets()` is not declared anywhere (it was removed from the language because it's inherently unsafe). I urge you to stop using `gets`, and *please* stop advising others to use it.

Comment: "scanf() & %s will read a string until a space is found after hitting enter." is _somewhat_ correct but oversimplifies the true functionality.  `"%s"` _begins_ by reading and discarding white-space, then it saves non-white-space `char` until eventually encountering white-space or `EOF`.  It, like `gets()` is not buffer size protected and both should not be used.  `fgets()` is a better approach.