# Given a String array, how to create a second array which is a rearrangement of the original?

Tags: java, shuffle

I am trying to create a method to takes an array of names and returns a copy of the list with the names randomly rearranged. The code below returns a new list with duplicated names. what can I do to shuffle names of the new list instead?

```
public static String[] shuffle(String []names)
{
    int num =0;  
    String [] newArray = new String [names.length];
    Random r = new Random (); 
    for(int i = 0; i<names.length; i++){
        num = r.nextInt(names.length);
        if((i-1)!=num){
            newArray[i]=names[num];
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have suggested there are already other cleaver/easy ways to do this, but to solve the issue in your code you need to make the newArray a copy of the names array (you can can use Arrays.copyOf) and then properly swap the values, like:

```
if(i!=num){
   String aux=newArray[i];
   newArray[i]=newArray[num];
   newArray[num]=aux;
}
```

Comment: No. (1) The algorithm will not return a permutation - it might contain duplicates. (2) There is no point in `aux` at this point, `newArray[i] == null`, so you are basically manipulating the original and putting `null`s in it (which might later flow to `newArray` in later permutations). Also, if you are thinking about a swap in the same array, then this solution is biased, since the random number must be selected in range `[0,i]` to get a uniformly distributed permutation.

Comment: Thanks @amid, you were partially right. I was not creating duplicates, because I assumed that I was working on the original array. I updated my answer. Also nextInt is generating uniformly distributed values so he will get a correct permutation.

Comment: Each int will be uniformly distributed, but the permutation itself won't be.(some solutions are more likely then others, this is not a desired feature) [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5131341/572670) discusses this issue. (It is a bit complex issue I admit, but it is an important one). Moreover - the solution still does not work - (last line is still `names` rather then `newArray`, and you need to fill `newArray` before starting, otherwise - it is just bunch of `null`s moving around)

Comment: @amid Producing permutations like this it will not produce uniform distributed permutations, but the permutation is still valid. And he needs only one permutation. My answer was ment only to help him figure what was the issue in his code. Anyway, thanks I learned something new.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) to shuffle a list.

If you are eager to do it by your own - have a look on [fisher-yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

(Pseudo code:)

```
for (i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) 
    swap(names,i,r.nextInt(i+1));
```

(Where `swap()` is a standard swapping function to swap two elements in an array)

(Note, if you want a new instance with the shuffled array - just copy it using [`Arrays.copyOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28U%5B%5D,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%29) before running the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Collections.shuffle(list)

[Info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

You can use the [ToList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) to make it a list for the shuffle and then back to an array with [ToArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28%29).

This may not be the most efficient but it is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public String[] shuffle(String[] ss) {
  List<String> list = Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(ss));
  return list.toArray(new String[ss.length]);
}
```