# Please help me understand this piece of code

Tags: java

I have a java project done for school. This is a piece of code which i am having a hard time to understand its logic. Please shed some light on it.

```
for(int i = 0; i< leftbut.length; i++){
          int randomNumber =(int)(Math.random()*leftbut.length);
             tempNum = leftbut[randomNumber];
            leftbut[randomNumber] = leftbut[i];
            leftbut[i]=tempNum;      

     }
```

The leftbut in this case is actually an array of 9 buttons.
This code is supposed to shuffle the 9 buttons in different positions.
I just cant understand how this code works.

Comment: you want us to do your homework for you?

Comment: wasn't the answer useful?

Comment: I am not asking you to do. Since this is a group project my partner did this part of the coding. I just want this to make sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The code generate a random [permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of the original array.**

However, note that this is biased - it does not generate all permutations in uniform distribution. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131341/what-distribution-do-you-get-from-this-broken-random-shuffle) discusses what is the affect of this bias.

To overcome this issue - you might want to have a look on **[fisher yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)** (which main difference is, to generate a random number in range [i,n) in each iteration instead of in range [0,n).)

---

**EDIT:**

You might better understand it if you encapsulate the assignments in a method:

```
private static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) { 
       tempNum = array[j];
       array[j] = array[i];
       array[i]=tempNum; 
}
```

Now, the code will be simpler to follow:

```
for(int i = 0; i< leftbut.length; i++) {
          //choose a random index in the array
          int randomNumber =(int)(Math.random()*leftbut.length);
          //swap the element in index i with the random element chosen in the array
          swap(leftbut, i, randomNumber);
}
```

The idea is you `swap()` each element in the array with a random index. This random index is chosen randomly from the array, and its index is denoted as `randomNumber`.

Since you only `swap()` items around, you can easily prove that the output array is a permutation of the original.

Comment: All the 9 buttons contain an ImageIcon. If this code randomly generates numbers which shuffles the JButton. There will be duplicate buttons with duplicate ImageIcon no?

Comment: @user2016977 A permutation contains no doubles, so if the elements in the original list are all unique, the result list will have all elements unique as well.

Comment: What is a simple way to explain this?

Comment: Thank you Amit. I am working on it to understand. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It just 9 times randomly swaps to elements of leftbut array.

Comment: All the 9 buttons contain an ImageIcon. If this code randomly generates numbers which shuffles the JButton. There will be duplicate buttons with duplicate ImageIcon no?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i< leftbut.length; i++){
```

Is a loop, it inizialize variable i to 0, and increment it each loop by 1

```
int randomNumber =(int)(Math.random()*leftbut.length);
```

declare the integer variable randomNumber and assign a random value in range 0 - length of array

```
 tempNum = leftbut[randomNumber];         
 leftbut[randomNumber] = leftbut[i];
 leftbut[i]=tempNum;
```

this actually invert the 2 buttons position in the array, the value i become the random one and viceversa