# Can anyone please explain to me the following Java code?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

The following code shuffles playing cards in a game. I have to explain what the code does in a presentation. I am a newbie in Java coding, so can anyone please explain to me the following code line by line:

```
// Deck shuffling method
public void shuffleDeck() {
    //Seed the Random instance with nanoTime
    Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        int swapIndex = random.nextInt(52);
        if (swapIndex != i) {
            PlayingCard temp = cardDeckArray[i];
            cardDeckArray[i] = cardDeckArray[swapIndex];
            cardDeckArray[swapIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
    cardIndex = 0; //Next card to be pulled off the deck
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. I don't understand why is it "too broad", and I understand how a novice programmer can easily get confused by the repeated swaps.

Answer (score 3):

This is a **shuffle of a deck**, at each iteration you swap two cards at random, and it will result in some random permutation of the deck.

However, **this algorithm is flawed and biased**, there are some permutations that are more likely to be generated than others, to use an unbiased shuffle, you should use [fisher-yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (which is basically the same idea, but generate a random number between `i` to `52`, instead between `0` to `52`)

The reason and results of this bias is discussed thoroughly in the thread: [What distribution do you get from this broken random shuffle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5131341/572670)