# knuth shuffle in python

Tags: python, numpy

I found out the knuth shuffle was done from the end to the beginning, such as

```
from random import randrange

def knuth_shuffle(x):
    for i in range(len(x)-1, 0, -1):
        j = randrange(i + 1)
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
    return x
```

However, I was thinking about why we cannot use it from the beginning to the end. Like this:

```
from random import randrange

def knuth_shuffle(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x), 1):
        j = randrange(i, len(x))
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
    return x
```

I found out the running time of the second function was always longer than the first one. Anybody has some clues of this?

Comment: What is the actual difference in execution time?

Comment: Note the second function does one more iteration than the first one. It should be range(0, len(x)-1, 1). Does it solve the problem?

Comment: Note: The second implementation is actually broken and does not produce a random shuffle. Always exchange from 0 to i and never between 0 and len(array). See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131341/what-distribution-do-you-get-from-this-broken-random-shuffle

Answer (score 0):

Your alternative solution looks perfectly OK. It does the same, but from left to right. 
I've tried it (on lists up to 1 000 000 elements), and I haven't noticed any significant difference in running time. 
How big lists do you shuffle?
What are the differences in running time?
Do they depend on the size of lists?