# Generating Unique Random Numbers in an Array using Loop

Tags: c, arrays, loops, random

So the question is to develop a [5][5] table, each containing unique numbers from 1-100 (*no duplicates*)

so here's what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int outerLoop;
    int innerLoop;

    int board[5][5]; /* Array Name And Size*/

/* seeds the random number generator*/

srand(time(NULL));

int number;

number = rand() % 101;

/* Start a loop to generate a random integer between 1 and 100 and 
assign it into the array. The loop runs 25 times*/

for (  outerLoop = 0  ;  outerLoop <= 25  ; outerLoop++ ) /* loop 25 times*/
{
    for (  innerLoop = 0  ;  innerLoop <= 4  ; innerLoop++   ) /* <=4 due to 5
columns*/
    {
        board[outerLoop][innerLoop] = rand() % 100 + 1;
    }
    printf( "%d \n", board[outerLoop][innerLoop] );
}
```

So I pretty much got stuck here.I'm not really sure about this:

```
board[outerLoop][innerLoop] = rand() % 100 + 1;
```

I simply made it up :/ Any idea guys?

Comment: the outer for loop needs to be `outerLoop <= 4` or strangeness will occur.

Comment: Another source of possible inspiration - [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). Though as it happens, the first algorithm shown is the same shuffling-based approach that [koodawg](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19363346/180247) already suggested.

Answer (score 6):

What you want is a shuffle algorithm

[Shuffle array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127503/shuffle-array-in-c)

To get your 25 element array of unique #s from 1 to 100; just create a 100 element array with the numbers 1..100, shuffle the 1st 25 from the pool of 100, and use the 1st 25.

```
$ cat test.c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void shuffle(int *array, size_t array_size, size_t shuff_size)
    {   
        if (array_size > 1)  
        {   
            size_t i;
            for (i = 0; i < shuff_size - 1; i++) 
            {   
              size_t j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (array_size - i) + 1); 
              int t = array[j];
              array[j] = array[i];
              array[i] = t;
            }   
        }   
    }   

  int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
        int a[100];
        int b[5][5];
        int i,j,k=0;

        for(i=0; i<100;++i)
            a[i]=i;

        shuffle(a,100,25);

        for(i=0;i<5;++i)
            for(j=0;j<5;++j) {
                b[i][j] = a[k++];
                printf("%d ",b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   

$ gcc -o test test.c

$ ./test
0 14 76 47 55 25 10 70 7 94 44 57 85 16 18 60 72 17 49 24 53 75 67 9 19
```

Comment: The classic shuffle algorithm is [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle). I *think* that's what you're doing, but my headache means I might be wrong.

Comment: @Roddy - if the unshuffled pack has all cards unique, the shuffle just changes the order - the cards are still unique. Initialize the array to 1..25 in order or whatever, then shuffle.

Comment: @Steve314 - 100% agree, but that information needs to be part of the answer!

Comment: If you're using Fisher-Yates, you don't need to fully shuffle your 100 values if you're only using the first 25. Once the shuffle has shuffled the first 25 items, it will never touch them again, so shuffling items 26..100 (which you won't use) is a bit pointless. For each random item you consume, you need to do one swap. You could even interleave the shuffle with the use of the items (like a co-routine or generator, but without help from the language).

Comment: Sorry - what I meant is that you still shuffle the full array of 100 items, but you only run the loop for the first 25 - the swaps can still swap values 26..100 into that first-25 range. To handle it, the `shuffle` function would need three parameters - the array pointer and two sizes - how many items total (100) and how many must be properly shuffled (25).

Comment: @Steve314 agreed, updated. Thus ends my legal obligation to make any further improvements! LOL :-)

Comment: But I haven't finished nagging!

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like a deck of 100 cards.

- Create a 100 element array holding the card numbers (1..100)
- Shuffle the array (=deck). (see @koodawg's answer and @Steve314's comment)
- "Deal" yourself the first 25 cards off the deck, into your 5x5 array.

Answer (score 0):

Just create array of boolean of size 100 : `bool numberUsed[100]`. Then in cycle:

```
1.Generate random number r
2.If numberUsed[r] is true, dont add that r anywhere and continue in loop
3.numberUsed[r] = true
```

Note that you need to use WHILE cycle with this approach, not FOR cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code to solve it:

- Create a "list" of length 100 containing the numbers 1...100 called "numbersAvailable"
- In your inner loop set `index = (int)rand() * numbersAvailable;` and the take the number `numbersAvailable.get(index);` and then do `numbersAvailable.remove(index);`

In Java creating a list is easy. If you like to stick to C you have to emulate this via arrays. (I can write down the solution, but this looks like a homework, so I leave something for you).

Note: In contrast to a trial-and-reject solution, this solution has the advantage of a fixed amount of time needed to construct the result.

Answer (score 0):

Since `int board[5][5];` allocates a continuous amount of memory you can initialise it with just

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(board)/sizeof(int); i++)
    board[0][i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
```

Or use a double loop like you did, but then you only need to loop 5 times in the other loop, or use `sizeof` to set the iteration count automatically:

```
for (  outerLoop = 0  ;  outerLoop < sizeof(board)/sizeof(board[0])  ; outerLoop++ ) {
    for (  innerLoop = 0  ;  innerLoop < sizeof(board[0])/sizeof(board[0][0])  ; innerLoop++   ) {
        board[outerLoop][innerLoop] = rand() % 100 + 1;
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that `sizeof` will only work on arrays in this way when the length of the array is known at compile time like it is in your example.

Comment: There is one condition: **no duplicates**!

Answer (score 0):

C stores arrays in ***row-major order***, i.e, the elements of row 0 comes first , followed by the elements of row 1, and so forth.

[image]
We can take advantage of this by viewing `int board[5][5]` as `int board[5*5]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 5

int main()
{
    int i, outerLoop = 1;
    int board[N*N];

    srand(time(NULL));

    int number;
    board[0] = rand() % 100 + 1; //initializing the first element

    while(1)
    {
            number = rand() % 100 + 1 ;

            if(outerLoop == N*N)
                break;      
            else
            {
                //Cheking the previous elements for no duplicacy
                for ( i = 0; i < outerLoop; i++)
                {
                    if(number == board[i])
                        break;
                }

                //confirming whether all the elements are checked or not and the assigning number to the array element and then increment the counter outerLoop 
                if(i == outerLoop)
                {
                    board[outerLoop] = number;
                    outerLoop++;
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }

    }

    //Printing the elements of array board[N*N]
    for (  outerLoop = 0  ;  outerLoop < N*N  ; outerLoop++ )
    {
        printf( "%d\t", board[outerLoop] );
        if(outerLoop % N == 4)
            printf("\n\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi sir, may I ask what does board[0] = rand() % 100 + 1; //initializing the first element mean?

Comment: This is because I started my `outerLoop` counter from `1` and for first iteration, the condition `number == board[i]` in `if` is comparing `number` with `board[i]` (which must be initialized before any comparison). You can omit that statement (`board[0] = rand() % 100 + 1;`) by simply initializing `outerLoop` to `0`. Try it!.