# Generating random arrays and storing in c

Tags: c, arrays, file, random

How can I generate Random arrays of integers containing only 0 and 1 values of size 8

for example

```
 randomval[]= {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0};
```

then it stores the value 0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0 in a file so if I want to regenerate new values for "randomval" it checks if 0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0 has been previously been chosen to make sure it has not been repeated and would generate

something else like  :  randomval[]= 1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0

then also store that in the file

Comment: why do you want to check for repetition if you want random arrays? In a random scenario you should expect repetitions, right?

Comment: Just generate random 8 bit values, e.g. `arc4random() & 255`, and write out the individual bits.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all to figure out how to do this? Do you know how to get random values? Given a random value some range, there are a couple of obvious ways to reduce them to 0 or 1.

Comment: @gat There could be numerous reasons to want unique values; that issue is orthogonal to how they are produced.

Comment: Yes Jim i am familiar with alot of the program already but was stuck o a algorithm to check for repetition i wrote out the larger scenario to try and help the people to understand my problem ! Thank you

Comment: @gat because i need to generate a IV for my des 8 bit Cipher block chaining algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each array of 8 binary digits (0/1) corresponds to an integer in the range 0 .. 255.
Therefore, to produce a sequence of 256 random distinct arrays 
 you can proceed as follows:

- Start with an integer array containing the numbers 0 .. 255.
- *Shuffle* that array randomly, as e.g. described in [Random array generation with no duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734774/random-array-generation-with-no-duplicates).
- Finally, take the 8 binary digits of each array element.

Comment: Thank you this was great i decided to take another approach with a mix of yours 

I generated a number between 0-255 then stored its bits into a 8 bit array and then stored the generated number in a file 

Then when i generated another number the second time i would check if that number is alerdy in the file THANK YOU !