# array of non repeating numbers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, random, unique

I have an array of six random numbers from 1-49 so far but some repeat eg, 12 15 43 43 22 15
is there a way around this problem?

so far I have...

```
int* get_numbers()
{
        int Array[6], i;
        printf("\n\n Your numbers are : ");
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
               Array[i] = ((rand() % 49) + 1);
               printf("%d ",Array[i]);
        }
}
```

any feedback will be great, thanks

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Do you need 6 unique numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a separate loop that goes from `0`, inclusive, to `i`, exclusive, checking the candidate number against the numbers that have been added to the array before. If the check finds a duplicate, do not increment `i`, and try generating a random number again:

```
int i = 0;
while (i != 6) {
   int candidate = ((rand() % 49) + 1);
   int ok = 1; // ok will become 0 if a duplicate is found
   for (int j = 0 ; ok && j != i ; j++) {
       ok &= (candidate != Array[j]);
   }
   if (ok) {
       Array[i++] = candidate;
       printf("%d ", candidate);
   }
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/u9FA55)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply throw out duplicates.

Another option would be to create an array of numbers 1-49, [shuffle them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6127503/10077), and take the first 6.

Answer (score 0):

The rand function is not aware of its previous output so you can put a check before you save it in the array

Answer (score 0):

If you get the first random number as `x`, find the second random number as the random of `random(1 to x-1)` and `random(x+1 to n)`. Continue in this way.