# What's the best way to randomly initialize an array in C, with certain proportions?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a 2D array that I want to initialize with a b and c values, such that 50% of the cells are a, 25% b and 25% c. Can you please suggest me a way to do this ?

EDIT : I have found a solution for 1D array that I can adapt for a 2D array (I initialize deterministically then shuffle): [Shuffle array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127503/shuffle-array-in-c)

Is there a better way ?

Comment: You need to make a start and provide some code. The probability bit for a is handled by `rand() % 100 < 50`.

Comment: I don't have a code yet, the array will be empty then initialized with 1, -1 and 0 randomly, but with the proportions above.

Comment: Any speed constraints?

Comment: @KarolS:   Nop the initialization is only done once.

Comment: Eg. size = 4, array[2][2] as 1D array , [a, a, b, c] shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

First, you fill the 2D array with a, b, c according to the proportions, then shuffle the array.

```
int size_a = size * 50%;
int size_b = size * 25%;
int size_c = size * 25%;
int i;
for(i = 0; i < size_a; ++i)
{
    A[i/WIDTH][i%WIDTH] = a;
}
...
```

and the same for others.
Then use the `shuffle`(in c++, we have `std::shuffle`) you get from the link while mapping the 2D array to 1D array.

Comment: That's what I plan to do, but I don't understand you when you write A[size_a / WIDTH][size_a % WIDTH] = a; ?

Comment: Because you are using a 2D array, for example, `A[3][2]`, when we map the 2D array to 1D array, `a[4] = A[4/2][4%2]`.

Comment: my mistake, it's `A[i/WIDTH][i%WIDTH] = a;`, so when you call the `shuffle()` for 1D array, the `array[j]` can be mapped to `A[j/WIDTH][j%WIDTH]`