# Shuffling deck of cards with a structure and enum

Tags: c, arrays, struct, enums, shuffle

I've got a main.c file which includes all start up stuff.
I've initialised the deck, but I am having trouble storing the temporary value of the array into a variable:
`

```
enum suit
{
    CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART, SPADE
};

typedef enum suit Suit;

enum face
{
    ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, 
    QUEEN, KING
};
typedef enum face Face;

struct card
{
    Suit c_suit;
    Face c_face;
};

typedef struct card Card;
void shuffle(Card * deck);

void shuffle(Card * deck)
{
    int temp;
    int y, x, t=0;  
    for (x = 52; x > 0 ; x--)
    { 
        y = rand() % x;   
        temp = deck[x];
        deck[x] = deck[y];
        deck[y] = temp;
    }

}
```

`

Comment: Well, `ONE` should be `ACE`, ;-)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127503/shuffle-array-in-c) helps you

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the address of `deck[x]` to `int` variable.

`temp = &deck[x];`

You want to do simple swap, so just assign the 'value' of `deck[x]` to `temp`, i.e.

`temp = deck[x];`

**UPDATE:**
As *cyco130* said in his comment, you can enable more compiler warnings using `-Wall` flag to `gcc` while compiling.
However AFAIW, this problem should be reported as an error by compiler since you are trying to store the `int *` value to an `int` without explicit typecast.

Comment: +1. I want to add that enabling more warnings would catch this in every major C compiler. Warnings are our friends :)

Comment: I've changed temp = &deck[x]; to: temp = deck[x]; and I am getting an error message of: incompatible types when assigning to type 'Card' from type 'int' vice versa

Comment: Is `deck` an array of 52 `Card`s? If yes, then have you initialized all the array elements with proper `Suit` and `Face`? If yes, then in that case you can simply use `temp` in the same way, with its type as `Card`, i.e. use `Card temp` instead of `int temp`.

Comment: I tried this and it worked perfectly! I used Card temp in my header file and referenced it in my function! Thank you very very much

Comment: You should accept the answer(clicking the checkmark beside the answer) if it solves your problem completely. :-)