# Shuffle generic array in C

Tags: c, arrays, shuffle

I have an array of pointer to a struct.

I tried to use the first answer of this question to try to solve this problem, but I got a seg fault:

[Shuffle array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127503/shuffle-array-in-c)

After try this code, I tryed to use this function to do the shuffling:

```
static void shuffle(void *array, size_t n, size_t size) {
    void * aux;
    aux = malloc (size);

    if (n > 1) {
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {

            size_t j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);

            memcpy(aux, array[j], size);
            memcpy(array[j], array[i], size);
            memcpy(array[i], aux, size);
        }
    }
}
```

But i got the following error:

```
warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer [enable by default]
error: invalid use of void expression
```

I got this warning and error 3 times: one for each memcpy().

### EDIT

I changed the code because I was trying to use this new one instead the old one.

Comment: Did your compiler tell you on which lines the errors were found?

Comment: The lines where memcpy() are.

I got this warning and error 3 times: one for each memcpy().

Comment: I changed the code, because the previous code was wrong!

Comment: Suspect `size_t j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);`  Lots of integer arithmetic that may not do what is wanted.  Maybe instead `for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) { size_t j = rand()%i;...`

Comment: @chux: That formula is an exact copy of the right in the linked answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator Agreed. I assessed the weakness of that formula in my answer below.

Comment: @chux: +1 for succinctly and clearly describing and demonstrating the weakness of the used range-mapping.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/60772575/1729784

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @Deduplicator good advice, need to scale the `j` offset by `size`.

This code also changes the `j` calculation.  I do not think what you have will work well.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
static void shuffle(void *array, size_t n, size_t size) {
  // This if() is not needed functionally, but left per OP's style
  if (n > 1) {
    char *carray = array;
    void * aux;
    aux = malloc(size);
    size_t i;
    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
      size_t j = rand() % (i + 1); 
      j *= size;
      memcpy(aux, &carray[j], size);
      memcpy(&carray[j], &carray[i*size], size);
      memcpy(&carray[i*size], aux, size);
    }
    free(aux);
  }
}
```

---

Clarify the weakness of `size_t j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);`

Substituting `rand()` with the values `0` to `RAND_MAX` in the formula will generate a sample distribution.  Example (i=0, n=30265, RAND_MAX=2147483647) generates the values `j = 0 to 30263`, 70957 times each and `j = 30264`= 41000.  This is a bad case and likely not the worst case.

Using `size_t j = i + r%(n-i);` generates a *nearly* uniform result.

Example (i=0, n=30265, RAND_MAX=2147483647) generates the values `j = 0 to 307`, 70957 times each and `j = 308 to 30264`= 70956 times.  Methods exist to compensate for this small bias.  Many SO postings.

Note: Inherit weaknesses in a poor `rand()` are not fixed by either of these methods, but method selection can make things noticeably worse when trying to use a sub-range of `0` to `RAND_MAX`

[Edit]

Holes appear with `size_t j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);`

Somewhere about `n > sqrt(RAND_MAX)` and `i=0`, values near `n` will not be generated.  Example: `(i=0, n=104643, RAND_MAX=2147483647)` does not generate values 104638 to 104642.

Comment: @Deduplicator Posted a comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127503/shuffle-array-in-c/6127606#comment35693230_6127606  Thought I'd give the owner time to consider before doing more.  The answer is not _wrong_, just has a weakness.

Answer (score 4):

Vou cannot dereference a `void*` nor do arithmetic on it in C, because it is literally "pointer to object of unknown type", so the compiler has no idea what to do (Some compilers allow arithmetic as an extension as if it was `char*`, but don't rely on it).

Thus:

Cast your `void*` to `char*` and do it with them instead. Don't forget to do your own scaling for the pointer arithmetic.
Also, `memcpy` should get a pointer, not the object pointed to, so use `+`, not `[]`.
Aside: Please avoid memory leaks, `free` any memory you allocated.
Finally, be aware that `random()` might have both a tiny range and bad statistic properties.
Finally+1: [chux answer dissects the range-mapping used in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23312695/3204551), showing how badly it was done.

[How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs)
[C99 with Technical corrigenda TC1, TC2, and TC3 included](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure, that you're actually compiling this as C code (C and C++ differ in type conversion)
2. Pass pointers to elements in an array instead of dereferencing them: `array[i]` -> `&array[i]`
3. `sizeof(void)` is not guaranteed to be defined, use `char`
4. Add some assertions to check parameters for memcpy(). One may use modulo to clamp i and j, although this mostly won't result in good random number distribution either.

```
static void shuffle(char *array, size_t n, size_t size)
{
    char* aux;
    aux = malloc(size);

    if (n > 1)
    {
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
        {

            size_t j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);

            assert(j + size <= ???);
            assert(i + size <= ???);

            memcpy(aux, &array[j], size);
            memcpy(&array[j], &array[i], size);
            memcpy(&array[i], aux, size);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
void shuffle(void *arr, size_t n, size_t size) {
  char *tmp;
  char *array;
  int i, r;
  array = (char *)arr;
  tmp = (char *)malloc(size);
  for (i = n-1; i >= 0; --i) {
    r = rand() % (i+1);
    // swap 
    memcpy(tmp, &array[size*r], size);
    memcpy(&array[size*r], &array[size*i], size);
    memcpy(&array[size*i], tmp, size);
  }
  free(tmp);
}
```

The simplest so far. Note there is no need to check for `n=1`.

If you really want to use `size_t` then modify the code a bit:

```
void shuffle(void *arr, size_t n, size_t size) {
  char *tmp;
  char *array;
  size_t i, r;
  array = (char *)arr;
  tmp = (char *)malloc(size);
  for (i = n-1; i+1 > 0; --i) {
    r = rand() % (i+1);
    // swap 
    memcpy(tmp, &array[size*r], size);
    memcpy(&array[size*r], &array[size*i], size);
    memcpy(&array[size*i], tmp, size);
  }
  free(tmp);
}
```

Thanks to commenters for pointing out issues with using `int`. (It is probably obvious the above code works --- that is returns permutation of the array uniformly at random, i.e., returns each permutation of the array with probability `1/n!`. It is nontheless a fun exercise to [prove this](http://www.columbia.edu/~cs2035/courses/csor4231.F09/rand.pdf).)

Comment: The use of `int` instead of `size_t` for `i` and `j` leads to problems when `i`, `j` need to be > INT_MAX.

Comment: `size_t` is usually unsigned, which means that `i>=0` will always be true.

Comment: You can still check `i+1 > 0`, which is equivalent to `i >= 0`.