# Random boolean array with fixed number of True and False values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, boolean

I want to create a 2d array with fixed number of `True` and `False` in each row. Here is the code to generate random array of `True` and `False`:

```
np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(N, N), p=[p, 1-p])
```

This code will give me an array of N*N with probability of `p` for `False` and `1-p` for `True`. Now I want to set fixed number of `False` and `True` in each row, and also random. How can I do it in Python?

Here are some other related questions but are not the same as what I'm asking:

[Example in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363399/randomly-sample-an-array-with-a-fixed-number-of-zeros)

[Example in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761998/random-number-with-fixed-average)

[Example but without specific number of True and False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528637/create-large-random-boolean-matrix-with-numpy)

**Edit:**
I should add that also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566744/generate-random-array-of-0-and-1-with-specific-ratio) link is not helpful for me as well. As it is seen in my question, I want to have a random boolean 2d array. So creating a 2d array and shuffling it won't be helpful ( shuffle is not shuffling the items independently, it can just move columns or rows), therefore it's not a random array. Please open my questions and let people answer it.

Comment: Shuffle a 1D array and reshape it to the 2D shape you want.

Comment: @user2357112 I want to have have the same number of True and False in each row. It's not working

Comment: "I want to have have the same number of True and False in each row" - that wasn't in your question.

Comment: @user2357112 Ok. Edited.

Comment: @user2357112 Can I remove it and post it as a new question?

Answer (score 0):

If the wanted number of `True` (or `False`) values per row is **one and only one** :

```
# size of our array
M = 5 # rows
N = 3 # columns

# create an array full of "False"
foobar = np.full((M,N), False)

# create a list of randomly picked indices, one for each row
idx = np.random.randint(N, size=M)

# replace "False" by "True" at given indices
foobar[range(M), idx] = True
```

This approach won't work as is for multiple `True` values per row, though.

Comment: Does it work if we just want one item per row to be False?

Comment: @Paniz Sure, just switch the two occurrences of `True` and `False`.  Actually it would work with any couple of values, they don't have to be boolean.

Comment: I need to have specific number of True and False in each row. It just works when we have one True ( the rest False) or one False ( the rest True) in each row.

Comment: @Paniz Indeed, and this point was highlighted in the first sentence of my answer. ;)

Comment: This may not be the answer to your question, but this is an answer to the question you asked – although it only addresses a particular case.  And as such it may prove helpful to part of the people having the same issue – as was I when I found your question.

Comment: True. Thanks a lot