# array sorting in randomly

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting

i have below code, that i expect should read text from file, store words in array and then print it out in random order. Final array is int, but should be char and it does not give me proper answer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    char message[10][150], buffer[150];
    int i = 0;
    int cntr = 9;
    char freeArray[9];

    srand(time(NULL));
    freeArray[i] = rand() % cntr;
    FILE *file_in;

    file_in = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(buffer, 150, file_in))
    {
        i = rand() % cntr;
        strcpy(message[freeArray[i]], buffer);
    }

    while (cntr >= 0)
    {
        i = rand() % cntr;
        strcpy(message[freeArray[i]], buffer);
        freeArray[i] = freeArray[cntr--];
        printf("%s", freeArray[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have alternative code, but this one gives me text without shuffle.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    /*declare and initialise variable*/
    char message[10][150],buffer[150];
    int i=0;
    int j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    FILE *file_in;
    file_in=fopen("test.txt", "r");
    /*stores and prints the data from the string*/
    while(fgets(buffer,150,file_in)){
        strcpy(message[i],buffer);

    }
    while(i < 10)
{
  j = rand() % 10;
  printf("%s\n",message[j]);
  i++;
}

    return 0;
```

Comment: It helps to add a tag for the proper programming language :)

Comment: _"it does not give me proper answer"_ is too vague. What _is_ the proper answer, and what did you get?

Comment: Compiler says: line 23: array subscript has type char. line 25: format %s expects argument of type char *, but argument 2 has type 'int'

Comment: The compiler speaks the truth. A format specifier of `%s` expects to see a `char *` but that's not what you're passing to `printf`. You're passing `freeArray[i]` which is not a `char *`. It's also complaining about `message[freeArray[i]]`, that `freeArray[i]` is being used as a subscript, but it's type `char`. I assume this is a warning, not an error. This might actually be OK, as long as your index isn't exceeding 127.

Comment: Initially, `freeArray[0]` is assigned a random number, and the rest is uninitialized.  Then you read in each line, assigning it to the index of `message` given by a randomly chosen element of `freeArray`.  You've got a lot of work to do...

Comment: @lurker: Actually, any index above 9 is going to be a problem.

Comment: @ScottHunter hah yeah you're right. Didn't check the limit on the declaration. I was just thinking in terms of the capacity of the data type.

Comment: `sort in random order`... what you want has a properer name called `shuffle`.

Comment: sorry for my english

Comment: the while loop that inputs the messages, can/will overlay prior message inputs, because there is no check to see if a slot in the message array is already in use.

Comment: this line: 'i = rand() % cntr;' will yield values in the range 0..8 because 'cntr' contains the value '9'.  suggest cntr be set to '10'

Comment: this line: 'strcpy(message[i],buffer);' in the alternative code will always place the message in the message[0] because 'i' is never incremented beyond the initial value of 0.  If 'i' is incremented, then the next while loop will be accessing beyond the end of the message array, unless 'i' is reset to 0

Comment: so there should be i++ after this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The following code:
-- compiles cleanly
-- contains all the changes needed to the OPs posted code

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_MESSAGES (10)
#define MAX_MESSAGE_LEN (150)

static char message[MAX_MESSAGES][MAX_MESSAGE_LEN] = {{'\0'}};
static char buffer[MAX_MESSAGE_LEN] = {'\0'};

int main()
{
    /*declare and initialise variable*/
    int i=0;
    int j;

    FILE *file_in;
    if( NULL == (file_in=fopen("test.txt", "r") ) )
    { // then, fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed for test.txt" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    srand(time(NULL));

    /*stores and prints the data from the string*/
    while( (i<MAX_MESSAGES) && fgets(buffer,150,file_in) )
    {
        strcpy(message[i],buffer);
        i++;
    } // end while

    printf("\ndisplay %d messages in random order\n", MAX_MESSAGES);
    printf("with possible repeated messages and skipped messages\n");
    for( i=0; i < MAX_MESSAGES; i++)
    {
        j = rand() % MAX_MESSAGES;
        printf("message: %d: %s\n",j, message[j]);
    } // end for

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: how to avoid repeating same words? and is it possibe to read text that is in one line (one sentence).

Answer (score 0):

```
The following is to answer the question given in an answer block

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <time.h>

#define MAX_MESSAGES (10)
#define MAX_MESSAGE_LEN (150)

static char message[MAX_MESSAGES][MAX_MESSAGE_LEN] = {{'\0'}};
static char buffer[MAX_MESSAGE_LEN] = {'\0'};
static char t[MAX_MESSAGE_LEN] = {'\0'};

int main()
{
    /*declare and initialise variable*/
    int i=0;
    int j = 0;
    FILE *file_in = NULL;

    if( NULL == (file_in=fopen("test.txt", "r") ) )
    { // then, fopen failed
        perror("fopen for test.txt failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    /*stores, sorts and prints the data from the string*/
    i = 0;
    while( (i<10) && (fgets(buffer,150,file_in)) )
    {
        strcpy(message[i],buffer);
        i++;
    } // end while

    for (i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(message[j - 1], message[j]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(t, message[j - 1]);
                strcpy(message[j - 1], message[j]);
                strcpy(message[j], t);
            } // end if
        } // end for
    } // end for

    printf("\nStrings in order are : ");

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("message: %d: %s\n", i+1, message[j]);
    } // end for

    getchar();
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: it works only when text is in columns (1 word/row) and as answer gives shortest word (3 times)