# Facing problems with Function questions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, boolean, flags

I'm facing a problem with this question:

Write a function void:

bool tossCoin (bool& flag);

The function returns true to indicate head (45% chance), false for tail (45% chance). There is 10% chance that the toss will fail, example not landing on a face; if this happens the flag is set to false, and the caller must call the function again (toss the coin again).

Test the function with a program that prompts the user for his/her choice (0 tail, 1 head) then calls the function to find if the user will win or not. If the flag is set to false by the function you must print a message that indicates re-tossing the coin is required,

Hint: you have to use rand() functions

My problem is I don't know how to begin approaching this question and how to do it correctly?

Comment: looks like homework.  hint: start approaching the question and then seek help.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you need a method that can give you a random with distribution `45% - 45% - 10%`. You can do it easily with the following algorithm:

```
int a = rand() % 100;
if (a < 45)
    return "head";
if (a >= 45 && a < 90)
    return "tail";
else
    return "fail";
```

But this is a very bad algorithm, because the distribution is not nicely shuffled (you have a huge interval of the same values). So, you can improve it by using the following algorithm:

1. Let `0 = head`, `1 = tail` and `2 = fail`. Generate an array of 100 elements: the first 45 elements are `0`, the following 45 elements are `1` and the last 10 elements are `2`;
2. Randomly shuffle your array, you can do this by using method [`std::random_shuffle()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/), or you can write your own shuffle using `rand()`, the detailed algorithms is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127503/shuffle-array-in-c).
3. Now you have an array with nicely shuffled elements, put it into an constant array, and you can use it in your function.

Comment: Certainly, I have tried approaching it according to the first step in the algorithm, however I was stuck in the rest of it. I don't know how to deal with arrays and rand() functions..