# How to avoid getting duplicates in deck of cards

Tags: c, random

So I'm trying to deal cards with my really small knowledge. I can randomize a card but I don't want to get the same card twice. I tried using "arrays" with "if" but I couldn't do it. Any idea how can I manage this?

Comment: [Shuffle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127503/shuffle-array-in-c) then iterate over the array.

Comment: If you remove the drawn card from the deck, then picking another card at random from the deck could not possibly give you the same card. IMO no need to shuffle, just pick ANOTHER random card.

Comment: Who the h decided that dealing unique cards from a deck involves shuffling? That would be just wasted CPU cycles.

Answer (score -1):

Start by making a **full deck** of cards as an **array**.

**Shuffle** the array using say, 1000 **random** **swaps**.

Have a **counter** for how much of the array you have dealt so far, starting at zero, and every time you '**deal**' a card, **increment** that counter by one.

Comment: The [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle) will do a better job. See the comment by @clcto for more info and sample code.

Comment: Yeah, I don't claim at all that swapping is the best way to shuffle, but it is a extremely easy method to implement, and so I recommend it especially for novices.

Comment: The Fisher-Yates shuffle kind of does (N-1) random swaps but with one index given by a counter. I don't think it's more difficult to implement than just 1000 random swaps.

Answer (score -1):

Create a card object that contains a boolean of whether or not you have seen the card already.  Then when you pick a new card, ask the card if it has been seen, if yes then pick again until you do not get one that has already been seen.

Comment: I didn't know you could create objects in c.

Comment: @KubilayDoğru - if that is indeed the case, you need to make a step back, learn the language first, and then try to use it.

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to do. Look what did I write at my op. I'll be searching the ways this guys shows me but a little example with the explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: I get your frustration but stack overflow is to help people with their code, not to write the code itself.  If you really need help go to codementor.io

Comment: @KubilayDoğru - if you don't know that you can create objects in C, I'd say you are getting ahead of yourself. Learn about `struct`, learn about functions and arrays, learn about memory, then you will know how to create card objects, how to create a deck of cards, how to draw from the deck, how to shuffle or split, how to sort the deck. It is very easy, but you need to know the language first. You can't learn it by trying to use it without knowing the basics. You can and will later learn from practice, but before that, you need the basic stuff.