# Remove duplicates from arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to make a card-game, and my plan is to make an array that first holds 1-10, then J-A, then the colors, so three different arrays and different variables with ints and chars.

However, I'm stuck with the problem now that I want to remove duplicates from the array, but i dont really know how to do it, I've read some facts but I need a better explanatin and hur it would look code-wise.

This is how my code looks so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{

    int arrays[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    char* color[4] = { "Diamond", "Spade", "Heart", "Clubs" };
    int i;
    int *number;


    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        number = arrays[rand() % 10];
        if (number ) { //Its here where i want to remove the duplicates
            continue;
        }
        else {
            printf("%d ", number);
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

I would be greatly thankful for an explanation on how to do it, I tried with variables holding the value of arrays[i] but then all the numbers will be removed.

Comment: In your example you don't have any duplicates, what do you mean by *remove duplicates*? Please provide an example, e.g.: `number == 5` -> I want X to happen.

Comment: "remove duplicates from arrays". Your arrays do not contain any duplicates. Can you please explain what you mean more clearly?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you are right, I'm removing it

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but `arrays[10]` is not needed at all, you can remove this array and simplify your program. I leave this as an exercicse to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it would be better to create one array of all the cards (like deck) and then [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127503/shuffle-array-in-c) the array, instead of using random select..
Then you can take the top 10 cards without any duplicates.

Theoretically with random select, you can select each time cards that already "drawn", and it will be waste of time (the more cards you drawn the less chance you hit no-drawn card).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that in the loop if you have "drawn" a number, you don't want to draw the same number again? Then you could have another array with a flag saying if the *index* have been "drawn" before, and if it have then draw again.