# Shuffling function not working properly

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have created a shuffling program that uses a 5X5 array and a vector. The vector should store the values 1 through 25 inclusive and the array should just have 0 for each element. Once the shuffle() function is passed it should randomly position the 1 through 25 values of the vector in the array.

```
void Match::shuffle() {

    std::vector<int> vec(25);

    int randNum = rand() % (vec.size());

    for (int i = 1; i < 26; i ++) {
            vec.push_back(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            backArr[i][j] = vec.at(randNum);
            vec.erase(vec.begin() + randNum);

            randNum = rand()%vec.size();
            }
    }
```

}

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: [MCVE] is needed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127503/shuffle-array-in-c. This might help

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/
see this also

Comment: I thought creating a std::vector of 25 entries, followed by 25 `push_backs` ends up with a vector of size 50

Answer (score 0):

In the last run (i.e., after `backArr[i][j]` has been set) you remove the last element from the vector and calculate `randNum = rand()%vec.size();` which calculates `rand() % 0` which will fail.

Just calculate `randNum` before `backArr[i][j] = vec.at(randNum);` (also remove the `randNum` in front of the loops).

**Addendum:** As pointed out by @infixed in the comments, you also create a vector of 25 (default-initialized) elements and afterwards push 25 additional elements (due to this, the first part of my answer is actually not true).
To solve that, you either need to remove the `(25)` when declaring `vec` or replace the `push_back` instructions by corresponding vector accesses (mind the off-by-1).

Comment: Thank you so much this helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

why not use std::random_shuffle ?

Comment: I would like to avoid using std:random_shuffle