# Generate random letters in C

Tags: c, encryption, random

here is my code. I am trying generate random alphabet but i see same letters.
example: (**Y**HTGDHFBSHXCHF**Y**FUXZWDYKLXI) How can i fix it? just i need mixed alphabet not same letters. Thank you so much.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void random_string(char * string, unsigned length)
{
    /* Seed number for rand() */
    srand((unsigned int) time(0));


    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        string[i] = rand() % 26 + 'A';
    }

    string[i] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[26];
    random_string(s, 26);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so you're actually after [an algorithm for pemutations](https://ericlippert.com/2013/05/02/producing-permutations-part-six/)?

Comment: See [`srand()` — why call it only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once/).  Since you only generate one random string, you won't observe the problem.  If you try to generate a second one, you will.

Comment: yes actually i want encrypt a plaintext and i need random character key. i posted as an answer my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shuffle array in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127503/shuffle-array-in-c)

Comment: Just as a sidenote, when you say "encryption", I hope this is just for fun and games, since that kind of encryption can be cracked very easily.

Comment: just for learning C language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operation you are looking for is called a *shuffle* or a *permutation*. It is not sufficient to call a random-letter function 26 times, since, as you see, you can generate duplicates.

Instead, start with the string `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` and perform a shuffle operation. If you want to learn by doing such things from scratch, I recommend reading about the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) then crafting an implementation on your own.

Comment: yes actually i encrypted a plaintext and i need random character key and yes i need shuffle. Ok i will write my codes as answer:

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by having a pool of available characters, and taking one from the pool. Please note that your target string was too short to accomodate the string terminator. Similar to Fisher Yates shuffle.

Edit: changed the types to `size_t`.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH  26                       // the cipher key length

void random_string(char * string, size_t length)
{
    char pool[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    size_t poolsize = strlen(pool);
    size_t index;
    size_t i;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < length && poolsize > 0; ++i)
    {
        index = rand() % poolsize;       // a random index into the pool
        string[i] = pool[index];         // take that character
        pool[index] = pool[--poolsize];  // replace it with the last pool ...
    }                                    // ... element and shorten the pool

    string[i] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[LENGTH + 1];                  // adequate length
    random_string(s, LENGTH);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
QYMUSFALIZCXGONBJRETHPVKDW
```

Comment: weather thank you so much, but i got errors this line: `unsigned poolsize = strlen(pool);` **implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'unsigned int'** and i couldnt implement inside in your code, not yet :)

Comment: Well just change the types appropriately. `strlen` actually returns `size_t`.

Comment: I have changed the types to `size_t`.

Comment: Didn't you get the same thing with your own `i <strlen(cipher_text); `?

Comment: actually i was asking now how could i implement you code? i mean in my code inside :D

Comment: I don't understand you: this is an alteration to the code you posted in the question, which now does what you asked: no duplicate letters. If you want a key of 3 letters, change to `#define LENGTH 3`.

Answer (score 0):

**// why program get errors this line? (unused variable cipher_text)**

```
char *cipher_text, msg[255];
```

You declare cipher_text but you only use msg.

You could declare only:

```
char msg[255];
```

Comment: thank you Eliot i changed but now i got errors this line `scanf ("%[^\n]", msg);` **format specified type 'char*' but the argument has type 'char**'**
and this line `encryption(msg);` **incompatible pointer types passing 'char *[255]' to parameter of type 'char *'**

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste from cplusplus.com/reference

> The pseudo-random number generator is initialized using the argument
>   passed as seed.
>
> For every different seed value used in a call to srand, the
>   pseudo-random number generator can be expected to generate a different
>   succession of results in the subsequent calls to rand.
>
> Two different initializations with the same seed will generate the
>   same succession of results in subsequent calls to rand.
>
> If seed is set to 1, the generator is reinitialized to its initial
>   value and produces the same values as before any call to rand or
>   srand.
>
> In order to generate random-like numbers, srand is usually initialized
>   to some distinctive runtime value, like the value returned by function
>   time (declared in header ). This is distinctive enough for most
>   trivial randomization needs.
>
> ```
> /* srand example */
> #include <stdio.h>      /* printf, NULL */
> #include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
> #include <time.h>       /* time */
> int main ()
> {
>   printf ("First number: %d\n", rand()%100);
>   srand (time(NULL));
>   printf ("Random number: %d\n", rand()%100);
>   srand (1);
>   printf ("Again the first number: %d\n", rand()%100);
>
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: sorry for my bad english, but I cannot understand what you are asking for.  If you do not get the answer, because may be I let something in my head. It means that in C and C++ the function srand() gives ever the same sequence. To avoid it you should call srand() with a random value, for trivial useses the function time() does his job perfectly. than you call rand(). And you are getting a nice random sequence