# Understanding a shuffling function

Tags: c

I found on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127503/shuffle-array-in-c) the following function to shuffle any kind of data types:

```
#define NELEMS(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))

/* arrange the N elements of ARRAY in random order.
 * Only effective if N is much smaller than RAND_MAX;
 * if this may not be the case, use a better random
 * number generator. */
static void shuffle(void *array, size_t n, size_t size) {
    char tmp[size];
    char *arr = array;
    size_t stride = size * sizeof(char);

    if (n > 1) {
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
            size_t rnd = (size_t) rand();
            size_t j = i + rnd / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);

            memcpy(tmp, arr + j * stride, size);
            memcpy(arr + j * stride, arr + i * stride, size);
            memcpy(arr + i * stride, tmp, size);
        }
    }
}
```

I have been testing and it seems to work fine but I'm having a hard time understanding how and why it works.

1. How and why doesn't it swap an element of the array directly on `array`
2. How come it is possible to assign array to a char*: `char *arr = array;`
3. The offset `i * stride` or `j * stride` in memcpy functions is bigger than the total size of the array (`sizeof(array)`). How come the pointer arithmetic works here?

Comment: You can't swap an element directly. Not all processors have a memory-memory swap `XCHG` instruction.

Comment: It might be worthwhile for you to get hold of a C book.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Is there one you would recommend?

Comment: @fassn https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: A key point not mentioned in the answers is that Standard C does not allow you to do pointer arithmetic using variables of type `void *`.  GCC does allow it as an extension — and it assumes that the size of the type pointed at is `1`, the same as `char`.  Since `void *` and `char *` have a very tight relationship. See C11 [§6.2.5 Types ¶28](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28) — _A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type._ and references footnote 48) _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ and the footnote says _The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions._  The conversion of the `void *` to `char *` allows pointer arithmetic to work correctly in conforming compilers (as well as GCC and Clang).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better understanding I will shuffle the answering order:

2 - `array` is a pointer of type `void`. In C, pointers may be assigned to and from pointers of type `void*`. Any pointer to an object may be converted to type `void*` without loss of information. If the result is converted back to the original pointer type, the original pointer is recovered.

1 - It does not work the same for single elements, you do not have a generic type that can be assigned to any type. So the code is switching the content of pointed memory.

3 - `n` is the number of elements in array, while `size` is the size of a single element in the array. `stride = size * sizeof(char);` means `stride` is equal to `size`, as `sizeof(char)` equals 1. The size of the array `sizeof(array)` equals `n * size` - the number of elements in the array multiplied with the size of an element. Since both `i` and `j` are less than `n`, `i * stride` and `j * stride`
will never be greater than the memory used by the array. I wonder though why the use of this `stride`, as far as I know `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: "... I will shuffle the answering order" -- now, that's clever. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. `array` is of type `void*`. It is just a pointer with no interpretation, so we don't know what data type it points to. The number of elements is given int `n` and the size of each in `size`. It is done this way so the function can be used with arrays of any type.
2. `char *arr = array;` is interpreting the void pointer as pointing to a sequence of bytes.
3. `sizeof(array)` gives the size of the *pointer*, not the size of the actual array. The actual size in bytes is `i * size`.

The shuffle algorithm appears to be the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

I'll also note that `* sizeof(char)` is pointless, since `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.