# C shuffle 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, random

Want to shuffle char *array and make elements random order

I read [Shuffle array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127503/shuffle-array-in-c) but for int

I try

```
const char *words = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" }; 
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    int r = (rand() % (6 - i)) + i;

    int temp =  words[i];
    words[i] = words[r];
    words[r] = temp;
}
```

error though when iterate array words

please explain

Comment: How you can make array without [] symbol, and how can you convert char* to int simply?

Comment: You seem to have some misunderstandings about arrays and the element types. Please take a couple of steps back and go through your books, tutorials or class-notes again.

Comment: Simply, the first should be an *array* of pointers...i.e. `[]`, and then each element is a pointer to char... The question is not really that useful without the error messages that you're getting!

Comment: And no, you don't have a 2d array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in remarks you have several problems

> ```
> const char *words = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" };
> ```

is invalid because the initialization (and the rest of the code) indicates *words* is an array, so replace it by

```
const char *words[] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" };
```

> ```
>     int temp =  words[i];
>     words[i] = words[r];
>     words[r] = temp;
> ```

*words* is an array of `const char *` so *temp* cannot be an *int*, use

```
const char * temp = words[i];
```

Out of that

- to use the literal *6* is dangerous, use *sizeof* to take into account any change on *words* replacing 6 by `sizeof(words)/sizeof(*words)`
- the right type for an index is `size_t`,
- to not have always the same executions use *srand* for instance with the current time

---

For instance :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
  const char *words[] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" };
  const size_t nelts = sizeof(words)/sizeof(*words);

  srand(time(NULL));

  for (size_t i=0; i < nelts;  ++i)
  {
    size_t r = (rand() % (nelts - i)) + i;
    const char * temp =  words[i];

    words[i] = words[r];
    words[r] = temp;
  }

  /* show */
  for (size_t i=0; i < nelts;  ++i)
    puts(words[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
four
one
two
five
three
six
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
one
three
two
four
five
six
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
six
five
two
four
three
one
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
three
one
five
four
six
two
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors and flaws in OPs code.

1. array of strings:

```
const char *words = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" };
```

Not sure how the compiler reads this (if not complaining). An array of C strings should be:

```
const char *words[] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" };
```

2. magic number

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
```

`6` is a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) which is considered as bad style. It's better to give it a name. Even better: the value can be determined by compiler which improves maintainability of code:

```
int n = sizeof words / sizeof *words;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
```

3. usage of `rand()`

```
int r = (rand() % (6 - i)) + i;
```

`rand()` is a pseudo random generator with certain limitations. It shouldn't be used with `% n`. For certain `n`s (e.g. 2), this may result into a rather non-random sequence. The cppreference doc. of [`rand()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) gives a better example which I turned into a function:

```
int randomRange(int min, int max)
{
  for (int range = max - min;;) {
    int x = min + rand() / ((RAND_MAX + 1u) / range);
    if (x < max) return x;
  }
}
```

which is called

```
int r = randomRange(i, n);
```

4. idiomatic swap

```
int temp =  words[i];
```

If the type of array elements to swap is `const char*` the `temp` must be as well:

```
    const char *temp = words[i];
    words[i] = words[j];
    words[j] = temp;
```

---

The complete sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int randomRange(int min, int max)
{
  for (int range = max - min;;) {
    int x = min + rand() / ((RAND_MAX + 1u) / range);
    if (x < max) return x;
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  /* an array of strings */
  const char *words[] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" };
  /* let compiler determine size */
  int n = sizeof words / sizeof *words;
  /* shuffle */
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int j = randomRange(i, n);
    /* idiomatic swap */
    const char *temp = words[i];
    words[i] = words[j];
    words[j] = temp;
  }
  /* print result */
  const char *sep = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    printf("%s%s", sep, words[i]);
    sep = ", ";
  }
  /* done */
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
six, three, one, two, four, five
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/adffe5b00a94fe38)</kbd>

Comment: @TomKarzes Am I right that `random()` is part of posix standard? I failed to find a reference for `random()` in C standard library (or didn't try hard enough).

Comment: Also, here's the comment about `rand` vs. `random` from the man page for `rand(3)`:  Do  not use this function in applications intended to be portable when good randomness is needed.  (Use random(3) instead.)

Comment: I think `random(3)` is part of the Posix standard (not certain).  It's defined in `<stdlib.h>`.  I stopped using `rand` ages ago, and use `random` when I need random numbers.

Comment: @TomKarzes [random (3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/random): _Conforming To 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001._ It seems so. Nevertheless, for portable code, it's better to not to use `random()` for own functions - agree.

Comment: @TomKarzes cppreference [stdlib.h](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random) does not list it...

Comment: Yes, I think it's standard for Linux and other Unix variants, but not part of the ANSI C library.  See [How to generate a random int in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-int-in-c) and [random(3) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/random) (I think the second link is the one you posted above).