# displaying a random string from 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a random compliment generator program in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char compliment[3][30] = {"You look so beautiful!", "You are a great person!", "Your hair is so stunning!"};
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(compliment)/sizeof(compliment[0]);i++)
    {
        puts(compliment[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output of this program is:

```
You look so beautiful!
You are a great person!
Your hair is so stunning!
```

But I want the compliments to be displayed randomly and just one not all of them. How can I do this? which function should I use?

EDIT:
Thanks for comments. I did it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
int i;
char compliment[3][30] = {"You look so beautiful!", "You are a great person!", "Your hair is so stunning!"};
srand(time(NULL));
puts(compliment[rand() % 3]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: look for the `rand()` function to generate a random index

Comment: What do you mean with one at a time? if you want to pick one of the messages randomly, remove the `for` line and use `puts(compliment[rand() % 3]);` Do not forget to set the seed with `srand(time(NULL));` at the very begin.

Comment: Thank you I am reading about it now. Seems like this is what I need!

Answer (score 1):

First we can use the `shuffle()` function from [Shuffle array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127503/shuffle-array-in-c)

```
void shuffle(int *array, size_t n)
{
    if (n > 1) 
    {
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
        {
          size_t j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);
          int t = array[j];
          array[j] = array[i];
          array[i] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Add

```
#include <time.h>
```

And in `main()`

```
int i;
char compliment[3][30] = {"You look so beautiful!", "You are a great person!", "Your hair is so stunning!"};
const int size = sizeof(compliment)/sizeof(compliment[0]);
srand(clock()); // set random seed

int a[size];
for(i=0 ; i<size ; i++) a[i] = i;
shuffle(a, size);

for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    puts(compliment[a[i]]);
}
```