# Is there any difference between the following algorithms for shuffling arrays?

Tags: java, algorithm, shuffle

My Java textbook says that you can use the following code to randomly shuffle any given array:

```
for(int i = myList.length-1; i >=0; i--)
{

    int j = (int)( Math.random() * (i+1) );
    double temp = myList[i];
    myList[i] = myList[j];
    myList[j] = temp;

}
```

Would the following code that I wrote would be equally efficient or valid?

```
for(int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++)
{

    int j = (int)( Math.random() * (myList.length) );
    double temp = myList[i];
    myList[i] = myList[j];
    myList[j] = temp;

}
```

I tested my code and it does shuffle the elements properly. Is there any reason to use the textbook's algorithm over this one?

Comment: And I'm not sure why people are downvoting the answers. Sorry to those who have posted. Is there any reason why they were downvoted?

Comment: Your code is wrong, even though it will appear correct (it does shuffle, just not uniformly), it suffers from the classic [bad-shuffle bias](http://stackoverflow.com/q/859253/555045)

Comment: @AleksandrH The one with the most votes is incorrect. (sigh) The most correct is harold's comment.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, because of the "unrandom" nature of pseudorandom number generators, there's a bias towards certain indices being picked? Is the book's algorithm preferred because it reduces the chances of this bias occurring by limiting the range of indices between 0 and i and then decrementing i?

Comment: @harold Thanks for the link, looks like a duplicate candidate with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are in fact different.

The first algorithm is a variant of the classic [Knuth Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle).
For this algorithm, we can prove (e.g., by induction) that, if our random number generator (`Math.random()`) was an ideal one, it would generate every one of the n! (n factorial) possible permutations with equal probability.

---

The second algorithm does not have this property.
For example, when n = 3, there are 3<sup>3</sup> = 27 possible outcomes, and that does not divide evenly by 3! = 6, the number of possible permutations.
Indeed, here are the probabilities of outcomes (programs generating statistics: [1](http://ideone.com/ll50qs) [2](http://ideone.com/b0xkZm)):

```
[0, 1, 2] 4/27
[0, 2, 1] 5/27
[1, 0, 2] 5/27
[1, 2, 0] 5/27
[2, 0, 1] 4/27
[2, 1, 0] 4/27
```

For n = 4, the results are even more uneven, for example (programs generating statistics: [3](http://ideone.com/8Bfm6v) [4](http://ideone.com/fxhDm2)):

```
[1, 0, 3, 2] has probability 15/256
[3, 0, 1, 2] has probability  8/256
```

As you can imagine, this is an undesired property if your permutation is supposed to be uniformly random.

---

Lastly, the fact that we usually use a pseudorandom number generator instead of a true random source does not invalidate any of the above.
The defects of our random number generator, if any, are obviously unable to repair the damage at the later step - if we choose a non-uniform algorithm, that is.

Comment: For a more detailed explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859253/why-does-this-simple-shuffle-algorithm-produce-biased-results-what-is-a-simple +1 all the same.

Answer (score 3):

The first example is preferred as it ensures fairness in how the elements are randomly arranged.  In the second example, the elements are random but not equally random.

The first example is based on an optimised version which doesn't use Math.random.

```
Random rand = ...
for(int i = myList.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
    int j = rand.nextInt(i+1);
    double temp = myList[i];
    myList[i] = myList[j];
    myList[j] = temp;
}
```

From Collections.shuffle

```
        for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
            swap(list, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));
```

which is the same thing.

This can be quite a bit faster as it doesn't have to produce as much "randomness" which means less calculations.  Generating a double is far more expensive than a small number say between 0 and 9.

However, the first example doesn't take advantage of this and calls Math.random() any way. It only matters if you use `nextInt(n)`

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly, in the first example, it's impossible for an element to be "shuffled" to the same index in the array. In the second example, it is possible for the element to be in it's original index. Doesn't this change the results drastically?

Comment: @PrestonM `j < i + 1` so `j` can be `i` and no swap occurs.

Comment: No idea why someone was going on a -1 spree before. Guess that's just SO being SO.

Comment: @Gassa: As an aside, unless the answer is actively unhelpful consider **not** voting down. [Down-votes are not a substitute for communication and editing.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). Your vote is your vote anyways.

Comment: @displayName I don't mind downvotes, but without a comment it's like saying I could help you improve your answer but I can't be bothered. +1

Comment: @displayName Thanks for the guidelines link. I downvoted exactly the answers which (wrongly IMO) stated "no, there is no difference", or did not, in my perception, answer the yes/no question in any way. By the guidelines, they are what I percieved as "an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect", so I still consider that the right way to go. In this particular case, I retracted the downvote after the edit (see the current first paragraph).

Comment: @Gassa I appreciated your comment.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Honestly, I opened the question, and there were like 3 of 4 "no, everything is fine" answers. And your answer which didn't address the problem as I saw it. So I panicked a bit. Perhaps a better action for a clear mind would be to find a duplicate as @ harold did, then comment on every answer with it.

Comment: Hope y'all don't mind, but I'm not going to select an answer. I feel like all of you contributed a lot here, so it would be unfair to award points to one person over another. Thanks for clarifying all this, though! Who would've thought such a small block of code could have so many implications? :)

Comment: @AleksandrH I suggest commenting/upvoting all the helpful answers

Comment: One more question: if I wanted to shuffle a deck of cards, for example, then my algorithm would be acceptable because its okay for some cards to be shuffled more than others in real life, right? Our textbook gives an example algorithm for a deck of cards class and it uses my algorithm to shuffle that deck.

Comment: @AleksandrH card shuffling isn't perfect or entirely random in real life. Your solution could be good enough but why not use the fair solution which can also be faster.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yep, makes sense. Thanks again

Comment: @AleksandrH The duplicate link's answers cite Jeff Atwood's [The danger of Naivete](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/), and shuffling cards is the example there, too. As stated there, _if you shipped a real card game with a naïve shuffle, you'd have some serious exploits to deal with._ For example, if one implements naïve shuffle for an online casino, they should be prepared to lose money with it, not win, once the most cunning players discover the unevenness.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use your algorithm in place of the book's algorithm.

---

**Explanation:** Your book's algorithm starts at a current element, beginning from the last one, and then picks another element from all elements within `[0, current]` and then swaps them. This way a higher index element can never be touched again, *but it may still end up getting swapped with itself (which is normal)*.

However, in your algorithm you are generating the random index to swap with from all possible indices between `0` and `i - 1`. Thus, a higher index element can be swapped back to its original location during the shuffle.

---

The following code is not the equivalent of your book's algorithm. It will not leave any element in place, which is possible in your book's algorithm's case:

```
for (int i = myList.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    int j = (int)(Math.random() * i);
    swap(myList, i, j);
}

private void swap(double[] myList, int i, int j) {
    double temp = myList[i];
    myList[i] = myList[j];
    myList[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: This is not correct, the first algo can leave the element in the same place as does Collections.shuffle() which does the same thing.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: You are right - an element can be left in place. But the first algorithm will not touch the shuffled element again, unlike the OP's algorithm.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. So the important thing is not whether an element gets shuffled with itself, but rather that my algorithm may be unfair or skewed because some elements *get shuffled more than others* instead of there being a *uniform* shuffle?

Comment: @AleksandrH yes, you want the shuffle to be fair ideally rather than just kinda random.

Comment: @AleksandrH: I have updated the answer and added the code that I think should be correct. You understood rightly. You can replace book's algorithm with yours if they both behave the same. But as you see, they don't. And as you see, your algorithm is unfair.

Comment: This has the problem you were referring to `(int)(Math.random() * i);` will not produce `i` so elements will not be left in place. It's not as random as the code in the OP's question. In short, it is less correct.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Not having any element left in place is exactly what I'm attempting and that doesn't make the answer less correct. I'm not trying to give the algorithm that's same as book, but an algorithm that will truly shuffle the array.

Comment: @displayName it depends on whether you want to arrange them randomly and fairly or you want to bias the result to avoid not moving some elements. Note: you have a chance you won't move element 0. Collections.shuffle can leave elements in place.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Element 0 will definitely be moved and as I said, I'm not imitating any algorithm in my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any reason to use the textbook's algorithm over this one?

**No.** Your code and the text book's both have no rocket science based on the value of the multiplier. The core part is the `Math.random()` function. The multiplier in your book is `i+1` that has mathematically lower probability in getting a repeated `j` value whereas your code just has a bit higher probability of getting a repeated `j` value, but frankly speaking, it doesn't matter.

Although, your code would be slightly, really slightly, in fact negligibly faster as each time an addition operation is not performed.

Comment: So the only difference is that the book's version limits the index of j to somewhere between 0 and the current i (what I'm assuming you meant by lower probability of getting repeated indices), whereas mine confines it to the entire array from 0 to length-1 (and hence may get repeated values)? Shouldn't a truly random shuffle use "my" algorithm, since each index should (in an ideally "random" shuffle) have an equal probability of getting picked? Edit: hmm, maybe not. Thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the understanding of my answer. About a truly "random" shuffle, well a random number generating function is not random at all. Interesting read [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/124233/why-is-it-impossible-to-produce-truly-random-numbers).